# I set 'unique constraint' on schema.prisma but I couldn't look at the application of unique constraint on target DB

Tags: prisma, pgadmin-4

I'm a nestjs developer, and I'm using prisma for connecting to postgresql from nestjs.

As you see this post's title, I applied 'unique constraint' to a specific field on `schema.prisma` file and I also did `prisma migrate`. But I couldn't check this application on my DB (postgresql). I'm using pgAdmin4 for managing my postgresql.

```
// schema.prisma

model User {
  ...
  email String @unique
  ...
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsdoS.png)

If that unique constraint was applied well, why didn't pgAdmin4 show this unique constraint?

I will wish to get a good answer.

Thank you!